# Raycasting does not work if the distance is in "minus"

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why do raycast doesn't work when the number are negative?

so i have this code.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("ray Variable")]
    public Transform rayStartPos;
    public float distanceToCheck = 10f;
    public LayerMask layer;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        RaycastHit hits;
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayStartPos.position, rayStartPos.forward, out hits, distanceToCheck, layer))
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawRay(rayStartPos.position, rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck);
        }
        else
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawRay(rayStartPos.position, rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck);
        }

    }
}
```

Nothing wrong with this actually.

But if I put the "distanceToCheck " to 'minus'10 (-10)

Then the raycast is not registered anymore.
so here is the screenshot of my unity view
[image]

So my question is; how to make the raycast allow negative number so that it detect the wall?

or Unity just not able to handle negative ray?

Answer (score 2):

The definition for `Physics.Raycast` that you're using is the following:

```cs
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
```

In your call to `Physics.Raycast`, you are setting the `maxDistance` parameter as `distanceToCheck`. The distance to the wall is always going to be positive, so it will be greater than `distanceToCheck` if `distanceToCheck` is negative.

I think what you actually intended was to set the `direction` parameter as `rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck`, so it would match your `Gizmos.DrawRay` calls.

You probably want something like this instead:

```cs
Physics.Raycast(rayStartPos.position, rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck, out hits, Mathf.Abs(distanceToCheck), layer)
```

`Mathf.Abs(distanceToCheck)` will ensure the number is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the answer is easier and weird enough.
I will just leave this code here if some other beginners need it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("ray Variable")]
    public Transform rayStartPos;
    public float multiplier = -1f; //I add this multiplier
    public float distanceToCheck = -10f;
    public LayerMask layer;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        RaycastHit hits;
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayStartPos.position, multiplier * rayStartPos.forward, out hits, distanceToCheck, layer))
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawRay(rayStartPos.position, multiplier * rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck);
        }
        else
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawRay(rayStartPos.position, multiplier * rayStartPos.forward * distanceToCheck);
        }

    }
}
```